# Accessing injected stuff in the template

Tags: angularjs

If I want to do something stupid like this:

```
foo = 
   bar:'awesome bar'

app.constant "foo", foo
```

---

```
ctrl = ($scope, foo)->
```

---

```
<div ng-controller='ctrl'>
    {{foo.bar}} <!-- that won't work --> 
</div>
```

Is it possible somehow to access `foo` without putting it into the `$scope`?

Comment: If you want 'foo' watched, then it must exist on scope. If you want it hard coded, or dynamically inserted into your template (but not watched), you can from inside a custom directive, and providing a template function.

Comment: no I don't want that to be "watched" it's a constant. see updated question

Answer (score 1):

No, `$scope` is the "glue" between a template and its controller. If you're injecting `foo` and want that to be directly available to your template, you must put it on the `$scope`.

This would also hold true for the `link` and `controller` functions of a directive.

Comment: hey... what if foo is a constant?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming 'foo' is an app constant, you can inject it into your directive and use it within your template function:

```
app.directive('test', function(foo) {
    return { 
        restrict: 'A',
        template: function() { 
            return foo.bar;
        } 

    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller='ctrl' test>
</div>
```

This will render:

```
<div ng-controller='ctrl' test>
    awesome bar
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible with the controllerAs syntax, though you still have to put `foo` on something.

```
<div ng-controller='ctrl as ctrl'>
    {{ctrl.foo.bar}}
</div>
```

And then in your controller

```
.controller('ctrl', (foo)->
  this.foo = foo;
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, it's worth mentioning that $rootScope is occasionally used for this because template expressions can walk up the scope chain to find things. This is really bad programming practice in a lot of cases... EXCEPT in some. Here are a few I've found that make some sense:

- Angular ui-router docs suggest putting $state and $stateParams into $rootScope. They're used EVERYWHERE, so it's not necessarily evil because this is definitely a global, singleton service with identical functionality across the entire app.
- If you have a few constants (I wouldn't want hundreds) with app-wide scope and you're just going to have to pass them down the scope chain anyway by constantly setting them into each controller you make (for instance, a page-wide variable that points you app to a Dev, QA, or Production box?)... The value of pretending any part of this is "local" to a scope is pretty low. All software development is a compromise. I think the reduced maintenance overhead and convenience might make this one worthwhile...

In both cases you still have that line of code somewhere (usually in your main or top-most controller)... but at least you only have it once. :)